# How do I transfer Excel from one computer to another w/o installation CD?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2010, license, transfer

I have Microsoft Excel 2010 on an old computer, and want to transfer it over to a new one, but I don't have the installation CD.

I'm on Windows 7 32 bit. I found the exe in Program Files > Microsoft Office > Office14 > Excel.exe but if there's an installer, I wouldn't know how to find it.

Any help, or do I have to rely on torrenting?

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply copy the installed program over.

1. Use [ProduKey](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html) to recover your Office/Excel 2010 key.
2. If you don't have the installer download the matching version of Office using these [official links](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/18-office-2010-direct-download-links).
3. Use key to activate Office/Excel on new PC.
4. Uninstall Office/Excel from old PC.